# Determine if a Delphi 6 class object is a derived class using a class name in string form?

Tags: delphi, class, inheritance, rtti

For logging and reporting reasons I create objects that have the class name and message belonging to an Exception.  I do this so I don't have to manage the lifetime of the Exception object.  What I would like to do is recover the advantages of RTTI identification that allow you to tell if an object is derived from a given class using the "**is**" operator in Delphi 6.

Is there a way to use a class name in string form to tell if the class the string contains is derived from another class?

Suppose I have the class of an object stored in strClassName and that class is "derivedClass".  Further, derivedClass is derived from baseClass.  Is there a function I can write that can tell if the class in string form in strClassName is derived from baseClass?  For example:

```
// Hypothetical function that returns TRUE if the class in strClassName is
//  derived from the class passed in theBaseClass
function isDerivedClass(strClassName: string; theBaseClass: TAnyClass): boolean;
```

What would the body of that method look like?

Comment: Two things I don't understand from your first paragraph. First, why are you using exceptions to do logging? I get the desire to log exceptions, but not how you think exceptions make logging easier. Second, how did you *lose* RTTI in the first place, such that you need to recover it?

Comment: @RobKennedy - I don't used Exceptions to do logging, I log Exceptions.  When an Exception occurs deep in the recesses of a component, I create another object that carries the pertinent information of the Exception that is passed to other parts of the system for auditing and reporting.  Since I don't want to worry about the lifetime of another object, I store that info (like the Exception class name, message, etc.) in string form in the new object instead of carrying around the original Exception.  That is when RTTI is "lost".

Comment: You're using the exception's `ClassName` function, then? Use `ClassType` instead to get the `TClass` value directly and skip the `FindClass` route.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function isDerivedClass(strClassName: string; theBaseClass: TClass): boolean;
begin
  Result := FindClass(strClassName).InheritsFrom(theBaseClass);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RegisterClass(TLabel); // must be registered to be found by FindClass/GetClass

  if isDerivedClass('TLabel', TWinControl) then
    ..
```

If you don't want an exception to be raised when a class by the name 'strClassName' cannot be found, use `GetClass` instead of `FindClass`:

```
function isDerivedClass(strClassName: string; theBaseClass: TClass): boolean;
var
  aClass: TClass;
begin
  Result := False;
  aClass := GetClass(strClassName);
  if Assigned(aClass) then
    Result := aClass.InheritsFrom(theBaseClass);
end;
```